# How Catch the Error Message from shard Database- AzureSqlDB

Tags: stored-procedures, try-catch, azure-sql-database

I've had an AzureSqlDB which consist of 2 Databases likely Staging and Production. My Sp's are running in Staging and the Sp's that are in Production I've used **SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE** for calling the Production sp from my Staging Database.

Recently I've experienced an Issue. I've deleted some Sp's in Production DB then when I called my main Sp. I couldn't able to catch the Error Message which is 
**Could not find stored procedure 'DBO.MY_PROD_SP'.'.**

Though I already had the TRY CATCH BLOCK. But since it's a Sp_Execute_REMOTE type. I couldn't able to catch this particular error message.

This is the Error Message I got when I manually run the sp in my Stg DB

> Msg 46822, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE, Line 1
>   [Batch Start Line 16] Error retrieving data from shard
>   [DataSource=azure2017.database.windows.net
>   Database=PRODUCTIONDB].  The underlying error message received was:
>   'Could not find stored procedure 'DBO.MY_PROD_SP'.'.

Please help me to solve my problem.

### Update 1

This is my way of calling the Sp.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP01(ERROR_MSG NVARCHAR(MAX),NAME NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #TEMP01
                EXEC SP_EXECUTE_REMOTE
                N'PROREMOTEREFERENCEDATA',
                N' DECLARE @ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(MAX)
                EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  N'' EXEC DBO.[MY_PROD_SP] @ERROR_MSG OUTPUT'',
                N''@ERROR_MSG SYSNAME OUTPUT'',
                @ERROR_MSG OUTPUT
                SELECT @ERROR_MSG AS ERROR_MSG'                             


            SELECT @ERROR_MSG=ERROR_MSG FROM #TEMP01
```

With this way, i can able to get back the error message with in the Sp help of output parameter. But Let say if the Sp is dropped. Then the error would be like couldn't find the store procedure. In that case, i couldn't able to use the error_msg to bring back my error description.Since the Sp itself not available in the Pro Database.

So, in this case, how could I able to retrieve this error message ?

Thanks in Advance,
Jayendran

Answer (score 0):

Run the stored procedure with sp_executesql. sp_executesql will return the could not find stored procedure error.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Thanks your answer.I've already used the sp_executesql task . Still couldn't able to retive the Error Message. Please See my Updated Question **(Update 1)**

Comment: Let me share it with more people and try to get an answer for you.

Comment: Hi Jayendran. I have not received any feedback yet.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that in order to escalate. I'm waiting for the solution. Let me know if you want anything from my end..

Comment: None of the persons I shared this thread with work as Azure support personnel, They work in different areas of Azure and they some time have the knowledge and they can share it with us, but the list of persons is limited and they are very specialized. I shared it one more time. Maybe this time I can reach somebody with knowledge on the topic.

Comment: Thanks Morillo, i hope the same

Comment: Hi Jayendran, can you send an email with some information on your databases schemas, stored procedures at estienne.granet [at] microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
    EXEC sp_execute_remote N'PROREMOTEREFERENCEDATA',
    N'BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE @ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(MAX)
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  N'' EXEC DBO.[MY_PROD_SP] @ERROR_MSG OUTPUT'', N''@ERROR_MSG SYSNAME OUTPUT'', @ERROR_MSG OUTPUT
            SELECT @ERROR_MSG AS ERROR_MSG                             
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERROR_MSG; 
    END CATCH'
```

Best, 
Sumeet